# User Principal is always null

Tags: c#, .net, principalcontext

I am logged in under user User001 under domain DomainA and with password Pass001.

I use this code

```
//var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
    //ContextType.Domain,
    //"DomainA",
    //"User001",
    //"Pass001");

var principalContext = new PrincipalContext(
    ContextType.Domain,
domain, 
    userName,
    password);
var userPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(principalContext);
```

And `userPrincipal`  is always NULL.

How to fix it?

Comment: The question is not clear, can you provide more code and context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this code I found is working fine...

```
 using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName))
                {
                    var uGroups = principal.GetGroups();
                    foreach (var group in uGroups)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(group.DisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }
```